# How can I make a filtered tables from a big table?

Tags: list, google-sheets, filter, datatable

I have to make this in Google Sheet. I have a big list with 8 data / lines.

The first data is from a list. A, B or C in this example. And I have to make an another table filteres by A, B and C.

[image: Example]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Please see [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=FILTER(A1:I12; B1:B12="A")
```

or without leading numbers:

```
=FILTER(B1:I12; B1:B12="A")
```